# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline: Want to Fail The Gate But Not Fail The Stage to not seek Approval

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a "QA" stage that is deploying a package and after deployment I have a post-deployment approval.  I only want to notify the "UAT Post-Deployment Approvers" group when the package is a Release package.  I use GitVersion and Git Tags to tag a git commit.  The Build Pipeline will automatically build the source code with the Git Tag event because of the branch filter "refs/tags/v*" that I've added.  I have also used Artifact Filters in the Release Pipeline before on the Pre-Approval side to prevent entry and triggering of the Pre-Approvers notification to look for "refs/tags/v*", but this time I want to filter on the Post-Approval side.

Is there a way to filter AFTER a successful deployment, but BEFORE a Post-Approval so that the stage doesn't appear as a failure?  Why?  **Because the deployment was successful and now I want the Release Pipeline to stop and not go any further.  I don't want to ask for a Post-Deployment Approval.**  The Gate check that I currently have (Azure Function) will return a failure and thus will fail the complete Stage (what I don't want) and then not ask for Post-Deployment Approval (which I do want).  OR is there a way to set the Stage to success after a failed Gate Check?  Or, maybe set a Jobless Agent step to stop processing?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to filter AFTER a successful deployment, but BEFORE a
>   Post-Approval so that the stage doesn't appear as a failure? OR is
>   there a way to set the Stage to success after a failed Gate Check?

For these issues,I am afraid that it is impossible to do this in azure devops.If you set Gates and Post-deployment approvals in the stage, stage will only show success if both conditions pass.If either of these two conditions does not pass, the stage will show as failure.

In addition,AFTER a successful deployment, but BEFORE a Post-Approval,the stage shows the status as Pending approval, not failure.

[image]

Comment: That's the thing with ADO, it's a great tool and I'm always championing it, but I'm limited to what I can do with, except through PowerShell scripts or the Market Place extensions I've created.  I have to submit a request and wait if someone will ever make my wishlist come true.  This is another great use-case, but I understand that MSFT has to do what's best for the most customers and in priority.

Comment: It would be nice to have a Checkbox to ask "Fail [Stage] On Gate Failure?" And then be checked by default.  And then keep all of the same rules as they currently exists (run before or after approvals).  It already fails by default if there is a gate timeout, and already a check on what to accept as a success criteria, so that is already a process.  Just need to extend it with that checkbox to proceed to stop and leave it as a success or mark it as a failure if the Gate fails.